# Android app hangs when manually signing

Tags: java, android, keytool, jarsigner

I've got an android app which seems to hang after manually signing.

But it does not always hang:

- when I sign with eclipse everything -> works just fine
- when I sign with the debug key (ant debug) -> works just fine
- accessing activities which do not load .so files (System.loadLibrary(xyz.so); ) -> just fine
- manually signing with the snippets below -> the app hangs without any mention in logcat

Now I am using the following line to build and sign the application

```
ant release -f dir/build.xml

jarsigner -signedjar Hedgeroid-signed.apk -keystore /path/to/keystore/hedgewars.keystore -storepass "password1" -keypass "password2" -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -verbose path/to/project/bin/MainActivity-release-unsigned.apk hedgeroid
```

the keytool outputs:

```
adding: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
adding: META-INF/HEDGEROI.SF
adding: META-INF/HEDGEROI.RSA
signing: assets/Data/Fonts/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
signing: assets/Data/Forts/LegoL.png
... (summing up all the files) ..
signing: lib/armeabi/libhwengine.so
signing: lib/armeabi/liblua5.1.so
```

afterwards I zipalign it, but with or without it doesn't change the result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ps.

this is the logcat from the point where it starts to hang:

```
D/dalvikvm(12755): Added shared lib /data/data/org.hedgewars.hedgeroid/lib/liblua5.1.so 0x410a4110
D/dalvikvm(12755): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.hedgewars.hedgeroid/lib/liblua5.1.so 0x410a4110, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(12755): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.hedgewars.hedgeroid/lib/libhwengine.so 0x410a4110
W/ActivityManager(  192): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
W/ActivityManager(  192): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{4182f1c0  org.hedgewars.hedgeroid/.StartGameActivity}
D/dalvikvm(12711): GC_CONCURRENT freed 434K, 9% free 6659K/7239K, paused 2ms+2ms
D/TaskWidgetDataUtils(12711): In trigger refresh list utils
```

Comment: Seems you really have two variables: the build and the signing.  What happens if you take take a working release build from eclipse, open the apk as a zip file, strip out the certs files, and re-sign manually?  Or even do an export unsigned apk.  Also you could unzip the two version on your dev machine and diff the contents.